# How to use dynamic value of table column in the value of another column on INSERT

Tags: mysql, insert-into, mysql-logic, select-insert

I'm doing something like the below..

```
INSERT INTO example_table
            (start_time,
             start_time_type,
             end_time,
             end_time_type,
             duration)
SELECT IF(start_time_type = 'now'
           OR start_time < " . CURRENT_TIME . ", " . CURRENT_TIME . ",
       start_time),
       start_time_type,
       IF(list_in = 'store', 0, ( IF(end_time_type = 'duration',
                                  " . CURRENT_TIME . " + duration * 86400,
                                  end_time
                                  ) )),
       IF(list_in = 'store', '', 'duration'),
       IF(list_in = 'store', end_time - start_time / 86400, duration)
FROM   bulk_listings
WHERE  .....
```

Now as you can see for the duration, I am wanting to work on the resulting value of the `start_time` and `end_time`; however obviously the code below will not work as that will work on the *current* value of the column I assume and won't use the *resulting value* I am wanting.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a subquery with your computed values columns:

```
SELECT start_time, start_time_type, end_time,
       IF(list_in = 'store', '', 'duration'),
       IF(list_in = 'store', end_time - start_time / 86400, duration)
FROM (SELECT IF(start_time_type = 'now'
           OR start_time < " . CURRENT_TIME . ", " . CURRENT_TIME . ",
       start_time) AS start_time,
       start_time_type,
       IF(list_in = 'store', 0, ( IF(end_time_type = 'duration',
                                  " . CURRENT_TIME . " + duration * 86400,
                                  end_time
                                  ) )) AS end_time,
       duration,
       list_in
FROM   bulk_listings
WHERE ...) AS SUBQUERY
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how it works!? I see the first 5 selects, but why are only `end_time_type` and `duration` getting their values via the `IF` structure? Shouldn't `start_time` and `end_time` be doing that too?

Comment: I have added fields duration, and list_in to the subquery, since they are need in the main query. So, the subquery makes the computations for the new values of start_time, and end_time, giving it the same names. Then the other required fields are also selected. The main query does the calculation based on the new values of start_time, end_time.